# Nim cannot open 'opencv/highgui'

Tags: opencv, nim-lang

I'm trying to use this library https://github.com/dom96/nim-opencv a wrapper for OpenCV.

After running `nimble install opencv`
I can see the package in `~/.nimble/pkgs/opencv-0.1.0/`

But when attempting to use I get a compile error

> Error: cannot open 'opencv/highgui'

```
import opencv/highgui
const fileName = "g.jpg"
let img_colr = loadImage(fileName, 1)
echo img_colr.width
echo img_colr.height
```

Not sure what the problem is something to do with Nim import paths?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you compiling with `nimble` or `nim`? If the former then make sure you've got `requires "opencv"` in your .nimble file.

Comment: Thanks for the response @dom96 I tried with both... But I don't recall adding opencv in the .nimble file. I'll have another go soon. I thought it was a problem with the brew install of opencv, so I installed from source using opencv 4.0.1 but got the same issue

Comment: So I had copied your opencv source into my project, which started compiling. Adding `requires "opencv"` into the nimble config solved this mess. Now when I try to run I get `could not import: cvLoadImage`, my opencv can't be install correctly. I need to figure out how to link highguidll properly

Comment: Yeah, that's a DLL issue. Either that or my wrapper is so old now that the ``cvLoadImage`` no longer exists as a function in opencv. If you're on Windows make sure to get a 64bit DLL if you're compiling a 64bit binary.